# Yii - Include field from another model

Tags: php, yii, yii-cmodel

my question consists of two parts:

1, I'm developing small ticketing software for technical support. I have model and views for **Workorder** (type of ticket). I would like to include another `model's` `field/input` into this model. This `model` is called `WorkorderJournalUpdate`. It's basicly just table with `3 rows:` `*id, workorder_id, text*`. In this case, `"workorder_id"` is in `HAS_MANY` relation with "`workorder_id`" in `Workorder model/table`.

The reason why I want to include this `field/model` is to create unique journal record after each Workorder update, so it looks like this:

http://luzer.eu/pu_files/27844_RelationsTC.jpg

//Edit: It would be great, if I could add new journal entry on each page update and as well read all previous records.

2, this part of my question is simple. I would like to make rule in model to make certain
fields required, but only if other field is filled in. For example:

```
Order ID:
Ordered by:
```

If `Order ID` is not filled in, Ordered by should not be required. If Ordered by is filled in and `Order ID` is not, `Order ID` should be `required`. Is this possible with "`required` on" `rule`?

This is all, hopefully, somebody will be able to help me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this like can help you

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/

Comment: Hello Hearaman, I actually found this answer few seconds ago :) It was helpful, thank you, first part of my question is answered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420129/scenario-for-validation-rules-in-yii/17420594#17420594 watch my answer for scenarios usage in yii, or http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/