# Set Yii Scenario if checkbox is checked

Tags: php, yii, cakephp-2.0, yii2-validation

I want to apply required validation on textfield if checkbox is checked otherwise not.i tried by scenario but it's not working, For form i am using  'bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm' 
my Yii version : 1.1.16-dev

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420129/scenario-for-validation-rules-in-yii/17420594#17420594

Comment: Thanks ineersa, but that worked after page get submitted, it validate fields and don't allow to save. it should validate clientside like other required field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model Rule section

```
[['textfield'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->chechboxStatus == '1';
                }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                    return $('#demo-chechboxstatus').prop('checked') == true;
                }"],
```

or if you using any scenario then you can use like this

```
[['textfield'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->chechboxStatus == '1';
                }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                    return $('#demo-chechboxstatus').prop('checked') == true;
                }",'on'=>'create'],
```